# Generalize route coordinates

Tags: math, geolocation, coordinates

I got a list of coordinates (lattitude & longitude) that when connected to each other create a route on the map. However I find that these are way to much coordinates because the creator of the route was very accurate and created a route with a lot of curves.

I want to simplify this route by remove most of the coordinates so the route looks more like straight lines. Can someone give me a hint on where to start?

Comment: Fixed this by making use of the douglas-peuckler algorithm. However othher hints or tips are welcome!

Comment: You are encouraged to post your own solution as an answer as well.